# How to calculate the length of arcs in the given periodic function?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, periodic-functions, arc-length

I have this function
$$f(x)=-11 \cos x+11 \cos 2 x+6$$
with period $2\pi$. The plot of function is on the left below. Then, I want to know how I can calculate the lengths of the four arcs for which $-2<f(x)<6$  that is the plot on the right. Any comments or hints are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do you know the arc length formula?

Comment: See https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/arclength.aspx

Comment: @mrsamy Thanks.

Comment: @Vasya Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have a curve, $y=f(x)$, then the length of the curve between $x=a$ and $x=b$ is equal
$$\int_a^b\sqrt{\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2+1}~dx$$
Does that help?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Then, I need to calculate the roots of $f(x)=-2$ and $f(x)=6$ to find the domain of integral.

Comment: @sara96 exactly, my pleasure!